# jQuery.data(key) throwing undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have some checkboxes which are used to show/hide columns and automatically resize them to fit the screen. I've linked the checkboxes to their relevent columns using a data attribute and try to read this value using [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/). This gives an error of "undefined is not a function" even though a breakpoint seems to show I have set my variables up properly up to this point.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <span>Show or hide columns:</span>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="column-selector" data-column="selectioncolumn" />Selection via dropdowns
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="column-selector" data-column="listcolumn" />Selected items
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="column-selector" data-column="mapcolumn" />Map
</div>

<div id="selectioncolumn" class="col-xs-4">
    Div 1
</div>
<div id="listcolumn" class="col-xs-4">
    Div 2
</div>
<div id="mapcolumn" class="col-xs-4">
    Div 3
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#column-selector').on('change', function () {
        var numberOfColumns = $('#column-selector:checked').length;
        var sizeOfVisibleColumn = numberOfColumns === 0 ? 4 : 12 / numberOfColumns;
        var columnClass = 'col-xs-' + sizeOfVisibleColumn;
        $.each($('#column-selector'), function (i, checkbox) {
            var columnId = checkbox.data('column'); //Error occurs here
            //More stuff
        });
    });
});
```

by setting a breakpoint I can see that the attribute has been set and the dataset populated.

[image: attribute and dataset values]

However, the line `var columnId = checkbox.data('column');` leads to the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". What have I done wrong?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/otz8nrxn/)

JQuery version is 2.1.1 browser is Chrome 40.0.2214.111 m

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need convert `checkbox`(which is `DOMElement`) to `jQuery` Object

```
var columnId = $(checkbox).data('column');
```

Change `checkbox.prop('checked')` to `$(checkbox).prop('checked')`

Also in your example there are three elements with same id (`id="column-selector"`), I've changed to class (`class="column-selector"`), because id **must** be unique

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/otz8nrxn/1/)

Answer (score 7):

You need to cast checkbox to a jQuery element:

```
 $.each($('#column-selector'), function (i, checkbox) {
    var columnId = $(checkbox).data('column'); //Error occurs here
    //More stuff
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem you are having is in the jQuery .each() the element passed in the second arg in an element *not* a jQuery object. try this:

```
$.each($('#column-selector'), function (i, checkbox) {
    var columnId = $(checkbox).data('column'); //Error occurs here
    //More stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Some days ago I was getting a similar kind of problem , 
so what was happening whenever i wanted to get a data-id of a html element by this :-

```
$(document).find(".tile")[0].data("id")
```

it was throwing this error :-

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...)[0].data is not a function(…)

Actually the problem is find()[] is not returning a javascript DOM object so you have to convert it to a DOM element for having these operation  , So I did this ->

```
$($(document).find(".tile")[0]).data("id")
```

just added put that entire thing in **$()** that casts these into a DOM object on which you can perform Javascript DOM element related methods.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but you can also access the current element with the `this` parameter:

```
  function (i) {
                var columnId = $(this).data('column');
                ...
```

It seems that this makes it work in your jFiddle